# What is ChromeFrame

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

I'm confused.What is Chrome frame. Is it a plugin, that the user have to install on his browser or is a library (kind of) that developers should use? I thought it was the first, but then I tried to include jQueryUI from google apis and the first library is Chrome frame.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: in a small words. IE is one of the idiot for Web. google try to stop them by giving them support for advanced thing such as canvas , storage. so that's user can use the feature without any issue with site.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding it is in fact a plugin for IE that makes the Chrome layout engine available to IE... JS interpretation, Canvas rendering, etc.

Comment: Where?  I can't seem to find it available as JS, only as a plugin.  Would be kind of strange that the whole thing runs under JS and is then able to complete JS operations 10X faster under IE.  That would be like running faster with a broken leg just because you put new shoes on.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_Frame

Comment: "That would be like running faster with a broken leg just because you put new shoes on."
well said :), but take a look on this:
http://code.google.com/intl/bg-BG/apis/libraries/devguide.html#chrome-frame

Comment: If you mean this:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js, I believe the JS is just to initiate the installation of the plugin.

Comment: But nothing happens when I include it

Comment: doesn't matter. Thanks for the help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you can add this meta tag to your page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

If Chrome browser is installed on your system then it will render your page in Chromeframe.

If Chrome browser is *not* on your system then you need to add Chromeframe Google API to render your page as like Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
```

It will ask to install Chromeframe while loading the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a chat, and we usually use punctuation marks and words like **you** and **your** instead of **u** and **ur** ;)